# Help understanding Smullyan’s semantics definition for First-Order Logic

Tags: logic

Ref.to **Raymond Smullyan**, *First-Order Logic* (1968 – Dover reprint).

Some background :

> [pag.44] - *individual variables* (to be used bound) and *individual parameters* (to be used free)
>
> [pag.47] - *first-order valuation* (basically, the standard semantics for f-o logic) : based on a non-empty set $U$ (*universe of individuals* or *domain*) with the quantifier clause : $\forall xA$ is true iff for every $k \in U$, $A(k/x)$ is true
>
> [pag.50] – “ for a set $S$ of *sentences with parameters [we] consider a mapping $\phi$ form the set of parameters of $S$ into a universe $U$; for any $A \in S$, by $A^{ \phi}$ we mean the result of substituting for each parameter $a_i$ of $A$ its image $\phi(a_i)$ under $\phi$. Now we say that $S$ is (simultaneously) satisfiable in $U$ if there exists an interpretation $I$ of the predicates of $S$ into elements of $U$ and there exists a *”substitution”* $\phi$ mapping the parameters of $S$ into elements of $U$ such that for any $A \in S$, $A^{ \phi}$ is true under $I$.”
>
> [pag.51] – “consider the universe $V$ whose elements are the parameters themselves”
>
> [pag.53-60] – the basic construction in the proof of Completeness Th for a f-o formula $A$ amount to generating a complete tableaux with an open branch $\theta$ for a satisfiable formula $A$. In this way we obtain for $A$ an interpretation with universe $V$.
>
> [pag.64] – Skolem-Lowenheim theorem : let $S$ a *denumerable* set of formulas.
> ”We shall restrict ourselves for a while to *pure* sets – i.e. sets of closed formula with no parameters.”

*Question* - Why the restriction ? May we say that this restriction is due in order to avoid to “run out” of parameters in building the interpretation with universe $V$ ?

Shall we say that Henkin’s construction avoid this restriction assuming a denumerable set of **new** individual constants ?

Comment: had a look into it and not sure why it is

Comment: no it was just my reason to upvote the question and hope to learn from it, was wondering maybe it was to make sure the Hintikka set is finite , the rules  C and D may cause to make the set infinite, but am not very sure of it.

Comment: Going on with the book (see pag.79), I now suspect that the reason is "hidden" in the interplay between *strict* Rule D and *liberalized* Rule D. It seems that the initial restriction on *pure* sentences was necessary in order to avoid that the *parameters* introduced into the proof tree can "clash" with parameters already present into the formula to be proved.